# ASP.NET FileStream.Write Works Locally but not Deployed on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream

This works correctly when I run it locally on the server where it's deployed:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/TestPath/testfile.svg"), FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
 {
    fs.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
 }
```

When I run it remotely, it's not creating the file. I have a try/catch block around the whole thing and it's not returning anything in the error handler, so I can't figure out what's going on. I assume it's permission-related, but I'd expect it to throw an exception.

I gave write permissions to IUSR and the application pool identity, and that doesn't work either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is Fiddler or Wireshark in your future?

Comment: What do you mean by "not returning anything in the error handler"?

Comment: It's not hitting the catch portion of the try/catch, so I'm not getting any errors back. But it's not writing the file, either.

Comment: On the remote server, what is the path returned by `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/TestPath/testfile.svg")`?  Is it where you expected the file to be?

Comment: I'm unable to do remote debugging on the server, so I can't verify that.